# match optional special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a question that has asked before in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510289/python-regex-match-optional-square-brackets), but there is no right answer in the link. I have some sql query text and I want to get all function's names (the whole name, contain schema) that has created in these.
my string may be like this:

```
 create function [SN].[FunctionName]   test1 test1 ...
 create function SN.FunctionName   test2 test2 ...
 create function functionName   test3 test3 ...
```

and I want to get both [SN].[FunctionName] and SN.FunctionName,
I tried this regex :

```
create function (.*?\]\.\[.*?\])
```

but this returns only the first statement, how can I make those brackets optional in the regex expression?

Comment: Don't you want to get also `functionName`?

Comment: yes , I want and I'll Use '()' to capture it

Comment: Then, please check my answer. The one you accepted has at least 1 severe issue in the sample code, and does not allow the name without periods and square brackets.

Comment: you'r right. but your answer return schema-less function too, and I dont want that(I mentioned my needed answers).in addition Taky's answer had some usefull description(although you add descriptions too , but after my check). but you helped me and I'm thanksfull.

Comment: So, you only want those function names that have a period in them? Ok, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
create function\s+\[?\w+\]?\.\[?\w+\]?

val regExp = "create function" + //required string literal
  "\s+" +  //allow to have several spaces before the function name
  "\[?" +  // '[' is special character, so we quote it and make it optional using - '?'
  "\w+" +  // only letters or digits for the function name
  "\]?" +  // optional close bracket
  "\." +  // require to have point, quote it with '\' because it is a special character
  "\[?" + //the same as before for the second function name
  "\w+" + 
  "\]?"
```

See test example: http://regexr.com/3bo0e

Answer (score 1):

To make some subpattern optional, you need to use the `?` quantifier that matches *1 or 0 occurrences of the preceding subpattern*.

In your case, you can use

```
create[ ]function[ ](?<name>\[?[^\]\s.]*\]?\.\[?[^\]\s.]*\]?)
                              ^           ^    ^           ^
```

The regex matches a string starting with `create function` and then matching:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"create[ ]function[ ]
             (?<name>\[?       # optional opening square bracket
               [^\]\s.]*       # 0 or more characters other than `.`, whitespace, or `]`
               \]?             # optional closing square bracket
               \.              # a literal `.`
               \[?             # optional opening square bracket
               [^\]\s.]*       # 0 or more characters other than `.`, whitespace, or `]`
               \]?           # optional closing square bracket
             )", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=create%5b+%5dfunction%5b+%5d(%3f%3cname%3e%5c%5b%3f%5b%5e%5c%5d%5cs.%5d*%5c%5d%3f%5c.%5c%5b%3f%5b%5e%5c%5d%5cs.%5d*%5c%5d%3f)&i=create+function+%5bSN%5d.%5bFunctionName%5d+++test1+test1+...%0d%0acreate+function+SN.FunctionName+++test2+test2+...%0d%0acreate+function+functionName+++test3+test3+...&o=x)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<=create function )(\s*\S+\..*?)(?=\s)
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yN9eL5/2)

It captures everything between `create function` literal followed by one or more spaces and another space assuming the matched string contains at least one dot char.